# Remove /?home/ from URL (Remove Controller Name from URL And Leave Only Method) | CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, codeigniter, url

**Hi Dear Stackflow Community i am newbie in Codeignite coding so i hope you guys give me the time to fix this error thanks is advance :)**

1. So basically i followed a tutorial here and i disabled index.php from URL that problem was fixed but here is my .htaccess right now and i still have the problem of example.com/?home/signin or example.com/?browse/ Or /?admin/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)i=[^&]+(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
AddType text/vtt .vtt
```

But the problem is i followed every single tutorial here in stackoverflow on disabling the name of the controller from URL like /?home/ or /?browse/ and every single  controller like /?admin/ show in my URL i want a clean url directly with no controller name or the ? mark in it i tried going to my routes.php to change things in it following tutorials but still same issue remains here is how my routes.php looks like right now

```
*/
$route['default_controller'] = 'Home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Please help me i attempted every single solution but nothing yet, I want to disable the name of the controller from URL like /?home/ or /?browse/ and every single controller like /?admin/ shows in my URL i want a clean url directly with no controller name or the ? mark my controllers are Home, Admin, Browse, General, Payment, Updater can you give examples with them exactly so i can try please to fix the problem according to my controllers

Comment: Please admin or anyone help me i am waiting on someones help and answer

Comment: Hi 'here' isn't linked, what is it exactly that is the problem (any error messages)? and why is the solution below not ok. I'm not familiar with codeigniter but you probably just want to redo the routes with your own names. To your own controller.  It's just not clear here on the problem and what an answer would look like.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?
Where is the tutorial you followed?

Comment: I want to disable the name of the controller from URL like /?home/ or /?browse/ and every single controller like /?admin/ show in my URL i want a clean url directly with no controller name or the ? mark  my controllers are Home, Admin, Browse, General, Payment, Updater can you give examples with them exactly so i can try please to fix the problem according to my controllers

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:
this my htaccess

```
// .htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

```
$route['404_override']         = 'my404';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = false;

$route['default_controller'] = '/Home';
$route['home']                  =  '/Home/index';
$route['user-list']                     = '/Admin/users';
$route['setting']                           = '/General/account';
$route['payment-paypal']            = '/Payment/paymentByPaypal';
```

and access this way: http://localhost/ (this accesses a Home controller with the index method)
or http://localhost/payment-paypal (this accesses a Payment controller with the PaymentByPaypal method)

Comment: really sorry sir but your giving examples with spanish websites it did not work for me at all, my controllers are Home, Admin, Browse, General, Payment, Updater can you give examples with them exactly so i can try please

Comment: You can give an example of how you want to have your urls.

Comment: i want my links to be like example.com/signin rather than example.com/?home/signin i tried to add this to my routes.php here `$route['signin'] = '/home/signin';`
but still does not work it still shows example.com/?home/signin  please help me

Comment: have you changed your htacces?

Comment: yes i did it, but it returned the index.php to url i wish to remove them both index.php? and controller

Answer (score 0):

Modify your route file with this and my advice will be to read more about CodeIgniter routing method

```
$route['signin'] = '/home/signin';
```

routing work like this, update the route file as you need

```
$route['YOUR_METHOD_NAME'] = '/YOUR_CONTROLLER_NAME/YOUR_METHOD_NAME';
```

Comment: i want my links to be like example.com/signin rather than example.com/?home/signin i tried to add this to my routes.php here `$route['signin'] = '/home/signin';`
but still does not work it still shows example.com/?home/signin  please help me

Comment: How do you link that page? did you try to access just simply `example.com/signin` in your url or a tag from any page?